# Assigning pandas selection to a variable and then modifying it

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to select some rows from a pandas dataframe and store the subset/selection into a variable so I can perform multiple operations on this subset (including modification) without having to do the selection again. But I don't quite understand why it doesn't work.

For example, this doesn't work as expected (the original `df` doesn't get modified):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"a":list(range(1,3))})
subDf = df.loc[df.a==2,:]
subDf.loc[:,"a"] = -1  # also throws SettingWithCopyWarning
# ... do more stuff with subDf...
```

But, this works as expected:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"a":list(range(1,3))})    
mask = (df.a==2)
df.loc[mask,"a"] = -1
```

After reading the pandas docs on indexing view vs copy, I was under the impression that selecting via `.loc` will return a view, but apparently that's not the case given the SettingWithCopyWarning. What am I misunderstanding here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `subDf = df.loc[df.a==2,:]` the method you are using is actually `__getitem__` (`df.loc.__getitem__`) which is not guaranteed to return a view. When you assign something to `loc` (for example `df.loc[mask,"a"] = -1`) you are actually calling `__setitem__` (`df.loc.__setitem__`). Here, since it has to assign a value to that slice, it is guaranteed to be a view.

Comment: Thanks. This clarifies things. Now that I know what I am looking for, I can see it in the documentation as well at the [very bottom of the section here](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/indexing.html#why-does-assignment-fail-when-using-chained-indexing). I suppose there is no way to always return a view and the best I can do is to repeatedly do a boolean selection into the original dataframe?

Comment: @user1596422 Saving the mask like you did is the cleanest option in my opinion.  For more complex operations you can save the slices with pd.IndexSlice (for example `slc = pd.IndexSlice[df['a']==2, 'b':'e']` followed by `df.loc[slc]` returns the same thing as `df.loc[df['a']==2, 'b':'e']`).